Symfony : TextEditorType Field not being displayed in my CollectionField in easyadmin
I'm currently working on a symfony project with a easy admin dashboard, I'm trying to add a collection field in to my "Campaign" Entity to be able to add, edit, delete Products.
each product have a description, which i would like it to be in a TextEditorField in Symfony, to be able to add bold and italic text.
this is what I see in my easyadmin dashboard :

here's my Crud Controller :
CollectionField::new('products', 'Products')
                    ->allowAdd()
                    ->allowDelete()
                    ->setEntryType(ProductType::class)
                    ->setFormTypeOptions([
                        'by_reference' => 'false'
                    ]),

and my ProductType,
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, [
                "required" => true,
            ])
            ->add('description', TextEditorType::class, [
                "required" => true,
            ])
            ->add('tags', TextType::class, [
                "required" => true,
            ])
            ->add('price', TextType::class, [
                "required" => false,
            ]);
    }


    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Product::class,

        ]);
    }


Did you solve this issue? I'm experiencing the same

Nevermind - solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78001647/texteditorfield-does-not-work-with-associationfield !
